# Tensorflow Profiling: long duration without trace info

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I profile the training of a deep model architecture in Tensorflow, I see a long period (over 1/2 the total time) at the end of the trace without any operations shown in the trace.  Is this expected?

[image: Example Trace]

Per suggestion, I added `tf.Print` statements to a few tensors to get timestamps, and they match the timeline above.  I don't include all the gradient print statements, just the first/last 3.  It appears that calculating gradients is taking 360ms out of the total 490ms per batch.  Why is this not in the profiling trace?

```
2017-09-11 14:53:59.908936: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] dummy_input[0]
2017-09-11 14:54:00.021368: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] predictions[0]
2017-09-11 14:54:00.022132: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] total_loss[0]
2017-09-11 14:54:00.022495: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] grad[0]
2017-09-11 14:54:00.022673: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] grad[0]
2017-09-11 14:54:00.023230: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] grad[0]
...
2017-09-11 14:54:00.383078: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] grad[0]
2017-09-11 14:54:00.383580: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] grad[0]
2017-09-11 14:54:00.389668: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] grad[0]
2017-09-11 14:54:00.394650: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] train_op[0]
i = 3 : Duration = 490 ms
```

The wall timing I see in python per iteration without profiling is about 500 ms, which matches the trace duration.  What is going on during the 300 ms when no ops are shown?  Is this how long it takes to assign the updates to model variables?  Is there a way I can reduce this 300 ms of "dead" time to speed up training?

I am running Tensorflow r1.3 (installed from sources) on Ubuntu 16.04 with a GTX 1080ti GPU.

Here is the dummy example that trains the tf.contrib.keras.xception model and gave the profiling trace included above.  I see similar behavior when using real data.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.keras as keras
import time
import os

nclasses = 128
batch_size = 20


def main(unused_argv):
    # Specify GPU Index
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'

    # Configure session
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
    config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options,
                            log_device_placement=False)

    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        # Dummy random inputs
        dummy_input = tf.random_uniform((batch_size, 299, 299, 3),
                                        minval=-1,
                                        maxval=1,
                                        dtype=tf.float32)
        dummy_input = tf.Print(dummy_input, [0], message='dummy_input')
        dummy_reference = tf.random_uniform((batch_size, 1),
                                            minval=0,
                                            maxval=nclasses,
                                            dtype=tf.int32)
        dummy_reference = tf.to_float(dummy_reference)

        # Xception network
        keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True)
        xmod = keras.applications.xception.Xception(weights=None,
                                                    input_tensor=dummy_input,
                                                    classes=nclasses)
        predictions = xmod.output

        # Cross entropy loss
        loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(dummy_reference,
                                                     predictions)
        total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
        total_loss = tf.Print(total_loss, [0], message='total_loss')

        # Optimizer
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
        # Training op wrapper
        train_op = tf.contrib.training.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)
        train_op = tf.Print(train_op, [0], message='train_op')

        # Initialize
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init_op)

        # Setup profiler
        option_builder = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder
        profiler = tf.profiler.Profiler(sess.graph)
        run_meta = tf.RunMetadata()
        run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
        profile_op = train_op.op

        # Profile on 5th repetition
        nrep = 5
        for i in range(nrep):
            tstart = time.time()
            if i < nrep - 1:
                sess.run(profile_op)
                duration = time.time() - tstart
                print('i = %d : Duration = %0.0f ms' % (i, duration*1000))
            else:
                sess.run(profile_op,
                         options=run_options,
                         run_metadata=run_meta)
                duration = time.time() - tstart
                print('i = %d : Duration = %0.0f ms' % (i, duration*1000))

                profiler.add_step(i, run_meta)

                # Profile the parameters of your model.
                profiler.profile_name_scope(options=(option_builder.trainable_variables_parameter()))

                # Or profile the timing of your model operations.
                opts = option_builder.time_and_memory()
                profiler.profile_operations(options=opts)

                # Or you can generate a timeline:
                filename = 'tfprof.json'
                opts = (option_builder(
                        option_builder.time_and_memory()).with_step(i).with_timeline_output(filename).build())
                profiler.profile_graph(options=opts)

        # Profiler advice
        ALL_ADVICE = {'ExpensiveOperationChecker': {},
                      'AcceleratorUtilizationChecker': {},
                      'JobChecker': {},  # Only available internally.
                      'OperationChecker': {}}
        profiler.advise(ALL_ADVICE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Comment: You could insert `tf.Print` nodes that'll show timestamps. One time I've seen such gap was when the time was spent copying data from tensorflow to numpy ndarray, since that operation isn't traced

Comment: When I profile using NVIDIA Visual Profiler, it appears that backprop calculations are running for the duration of the "empty" period in the TF profiler trace.  I don't understand why the TF profiler trace shows nothing happening.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. It sounds similar to another bug that was closed before (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11803)